# Mgmt Vlan vs other SVI s

Tags: switch, vlan, layer3, interface, management

Think of a layer 3 switch. Assume that we have a management vlan and a mgmt vlan interface. And we have other svi's on the switch. The question is this. I know that mgmt vlan is for telnet/ssh, simply for connecting and managing the switch, but whats holding me from connecting to the switch through other svis. Whats the difference between the management svi and other svis?

Comment: There is no difference. Normally you would redirect traffic through a firewall or some other filter ex. access-lists of some sorts to deny telnet/SSH traffic on other SVI's except your management VLAN.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I appriciate it.

Comment: You should accept an answer if you think it helped you. Alternatively you could supply your own answer and accept that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no ACL created on the line vty 0-4 that would restrict the access to this switch or router, then there is no difference between managment SVI's and other SVI's.

The management SVI/management network, is the the type of network **from which** the device is managed and **where** networking components are in. Source IP and destination IP define a management network. This is a network department specific configuration. If this is not defined then there is no difference.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I appriciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Management SVI that is used for device management, have 
 an IP address like as other SVIs. As per standard design, Vlans are terminated at distribution layer gateway IP address and SVIs IP address are no more visible at other part of network except service domain nodes, but management SVI IP address advertised to every part of network layers like core, super core including distribution and access layer with in network. So, network administrator can easily access to device using management SVI IP address.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I appriciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking there is no difference between management  SVI and other SVI . However every virtual interfàce are configured so that servers , PCs are connected and provided interconnectivity among connected devices . Same way management SVI are allocated to network devices like switches , firewalls routers and other devices so that connectivity is established to access management SVI connected devices .

So there is no difference between management SVI and other SVI .